# Align input with labels to button without label (vertically)

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I want to align input, which has two labels with a button that doesn't have any labels so that they are both on the same level.

Here's desired effect:

[image: Desired effect]

Here's what I got so far:

[image]

I've managed to get this to look how I want by adding label with empty space before the button, which is not ideal.

Here's the code:

```
<Form>
<Form.Group widths='four'>
    <Form.Field>
        <Form.Input type='number' label='Input'/>
            <label>We can't find any matches.</label>
    </Form.Field>
    <Form.Field>
        <Button primary>Search</Button>
    </Form.Field>
</Form.Group>
```

Thanks for your help

EDIT: Here's the link to CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/v6kkmyzyr0

Comment: Could you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on e.g. [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new)? It will be easier to help you that way.

Comment: Added the link to the question. Thanks for suggesting CodeSandbox.

Answer (score 2):

I think that this is a styles issue and it depends of the design framework that you are using ( if you are using one).

Answering your question you could use flex to align the items horizontally
Here is the code : https://codesandbox.io/s/1oro0o6943

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { Button, Form } from "semantic-ui-react";

const App = () => (
  <Form>
    <Form.Group widths="four" style={{ display:"flex", flexDirection:"row", alignItems:"center",  }}>
      <Form.Field>
        <Form.Input type="number" label="Input" />
        <label>We can't find any matches.</label>
      </Form.Field>
      <Form.Field>
        <Button primary>Search</Button>
      </Form.Field>
    </Form.Group>
  </Form>
);

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

I've made it with inline styles but you could manage this in several ways!

Comment: Do you know of any way to make this work when I delete the optional label with the text "We can't find any matches." ?

Comment: That case i did this way : https://codesandbox.io/s/1oro0o6943

Just take the label out of the Form.Field and locate it as a row under the Form.Group. 

And change the style **alignContents: to flex-end**.

To check how its working change the flag **noMatches** at the top of the code

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm trying to figure out how to make this work with more fields as well. I think I will probably just use the grid to lay out everything how I want.

Comment: Yes, just try to orginize everything by rows and columns,the row is the container of the columns, this will make easier to handle the layout in mobile devices.

Comment: I tried this approach and it kinda work. However the button and the input are not properly align vertically
PS: removing `alignItems:"center"` make them aligned

Answer (score 0):

Try using flex

```
   <Form.Group widths='four'>
      <div style="display: flex;  flex-direction:row; height 
         auto;  align-items: 
      center">
           <Form.Field>
               <Form.Input type='number' label='Input'/>
               <label>We can't find any matches.</label>
           </Form.Field>
           <Form.Field>
               <Button primary>Search</Button>
            </Form.Field>
        </div>
    </Form.Group>
```

Comment: Sorry, this seems to move the button below the input field and center everything. I've added link to CodeSandbox in the question if you want to experiment.

Comment: @fuudge sorry I just updated my answer to `align-items: center` to align vertically, sorry justify- contents was to align horizontally I made a mistake